# How to identify the terminal from a script?

Tags: macos, terminal.app, iterm2

And don't say "`$TERM`" – it's always `xterm`.

How can a `bash` script tell what terminal it's running in, specifically whether it's iTerm, Terminal.app, or actually an xterm?

I ask because `reset` does not work¹ out of the box on Terminal.app and iTerm2. iTerm2, however, does recognize an escape sequence for doing a terminal reset (`\x1b]50;ClearScrollback\x07`), and if I could detect it, I could override `reset` with an alias that does the right thing. AFAICT, Terminal.app lacks a reset sequence, and [people resort to ridiculous tom-hackery to hack around that](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31872/how-do-i-reset-the-scrollback-in-the-terminal-via-a-shell-command/31887#31887).

My end goal here is to have `reset` work the same whether I'm working on OS X or Linux, working locally or remotely through SSH. (I don't want to have to try to remember which, and it's useful to do `reset && command-that-outputs-a-bunch` and have up-enter work.) Terminal.app and iTerm are throwing a wrench in this plan by not implementing `reset` correctly.

This means that simply overriding `reset` isn't quite it: if I'm on a Linux machine, it needs to know whether I'm using `gnome-terminal` or iTerm in order to send the right escape sequence.

Is there any way (even if I need an `ioctl`) to ask the terminal what it *really* is?

¹For the purposes of this question, reset should clear the screen, reset the cursor, and wipe the scrollback buffer.

Comment: Well, this is a feature, not a bug, or so they say. What happens if you open `Terminal.app`'s settings, terminal tab and set scrollback lines to 0? Does that disable any and all text above the current line, or just anything above the top of the screen? I know, it's not exactly what you asked for, worth a shot.

Comment: @nitro2k01: I'm not sure what that would accomplish? I *want* scrollback. I just want to be able to clear it now and then, preferably with `reset`, since that's what my fingers know.

Comment: As for your “reset” issue: to clarify, you’re expecting the `reset` command to clear the terminal emulator’s scroll-back content, but that’s not guaranteed to do that, because scroll-back is a terminal emulator-specific feature, not really a part of a terminal. However, Terminal supports an extension of the ED (Erase in Display) escape sequence to erase the scroll-back `ESC [ 3 J`. You can clear the screen, then use that, e.g., `reset && printf '\e[3J’`

Comment: See my answer here http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/113168/6883 for more details about the Erase in Display extension.

Comment: @ChrisPage: I realize that terminals are quirky things, but if you declare yourself to be an `xterm` (through `TERM=xterm`) I'd expect that you emulate a superset of the XTerm, which clears its scrollback on reset. (Just as if you sent the escape sequence for "blue", you'd expect blue.) Granted, my xterm tells me that `Erase is backspace.`, which I'm thankful nothing else does; that's just annoying.

Comment: @Thanatos: Keep in mind that the `reset` command is not necessarily used interactively, and that it sends whatever `tput` would send. It is primarily used to reset the terminal state, and may also clear the screen. Extending this to clear the scrollback is often not what users expect the reset sequence to do. Various programs may send the reset sequence to initialize state and clear the screen, but they probably shouldn’t discard potentially vast amounts of critical information from the scrollback. Terminal users can interactively use Edit > Clear All or Clear Scrollback.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `$TERM_PROGRAM`.

iTerm sets it to `iTerm.app`, and Terminal.app to `Apple_Terminal`.

Comment: Heh, OK, this is clearly better than my hack, +1 :). The hack should work for any terminal emulator though, not just those two.

Comment: There is no single way to detect every terminal emulator. For xterm, you can check for the $XTERM_VERSION variable, for example. That will take care of what are probably the three most popular emulators on OS X.

Comment: Accepting this, as it's a good start. Unfortunately, it's not quite this easy, as this variable isn't available inside an SSH session. I suspect there are configs that I can edit to forward it.

Comment: @Thanatos `sshd_config`'s `AcceptEnv` probably. As this (your shell runs on a different host than the one your Terminal runs on) is very important information, it really should be part of the question.

Comment: @DanielBeck: It's not strictly the case; I'd like to to do the same locally and remotely. What I'm going for is that typing "reset" into a terminal causes a reset of the terminal, no matter whether I'm on OS X or Linux, working locally or remote. I've edited this into the question.

Answer (score 2):

`$TERM` has nothing at all to do with the terminal emulator currently running, it is just your default terminal and can be set to anything at all. To get the name of the terminal emulator you are running, you can use `ps` to get the PID of the parent process of your current shell.

#### NOTE: The following will fail on OSX but should work OK on Linux

The PID of your current shell process is `$$`. From there, you can use `ps` to show a process tree, and print the PID of the parent of your current shell session:

```
ps -axjf | awk -v pid=$$ '($2==pid){print $1}'
```

You can then pass that PID to `ps` and tell it to print the command name:

```
ps -o comm=  $(ps -axjf | awk -v pid=$$ '($2==pid){print $1}')
```

That will truncate the name, it should be enough for you to figure it out but might not be good for scripting. To get the complete name, you could try

```
ps --no-headers $(ps -axjf | awk -v pid=$$ '($2==pid){print $1}') | awk '{print $NF}'
```

This is what I get on my system using a few different terminals:

1. `terminator`

   ```
   $ ps --no-headers $(ps -axjf | awk -v pid=$$ '($2==pid){print $1}') | 
      awk '{print $NF}'
   /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator
   ```
2. `gnome-terminal`

   ```
   $ ps --no-headers $(ps -axjf | awk -v pid=$$ '($2==pid){print $1}') | 
      awk '{print $NF}'
   /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-terminal-server
   ```
3. `xterm`

   ```
   $ ps --no-headers $(ps axjf | awk -v pid=$$ '($2==pid){print $1}') | 
      awk '{print $NF}'
   xterm
   ```

Comment: Doesn't work on OS X: `ps: illegal option -- f`

Comment: @DanielBeck darn BSD style, thanks. Could you try again with the updated version? Adding a `-` before the options should work according to OSX's [`man ps`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ps.1.html).

Comment: Better, but still not working. Output format is different (PID is `$2`, PPID is `$3`), and the parent process of the shell might be `login` (depending on Terminal config), with different params. However, *its* parent process is `Terminal`. `--no-headers` doesn't exist, you'd need something like `tail -n1`. And since all processes with UI have an [argument `-psn_0_...`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10242115), `awk '{print $NF}'` doesn't work either.

Comment: @DanielBeck well shucks then. OK, thanks I'll make it clear that this fails on OSX.

Comment: Note that this only works locally. You can’t use this approach to figure out what terminal emulator is being used on a remote client. The best answer is to look for variables like $TERM_PROGRAM (as mentioned in @DanielBeck’s answer) and $XTERM_VERSION to deduce the emulator application.

Comment: @ChrisPage how will this not work remotely? When would you be running a terminal emulator on a remote session? You mean if you are connecting via a VNC client? Unfortunately, the variables you mention are not set in Linux, at least not usually.

Comment: @terdon, I mean if you’re using a terminal emulator to connect to a remote machine. The shell is on the remote host and is not a child of the terminal emulator process. Some systems are set up to transmit TERM* environment variables through ssh. If yours isn’t, it’s straightforward to add the appropriate variable names (and wildcards are supported) to the ssh configuration on the host and client as appropriate.

Comment: @ChrisPage oh, OK. Yes, obviously if you run this on a remote system it won't work but what's the point of running a command to identify your local terminal emulator on a remote system? I can only think of running a remote script through `ssh user@host script.sh`.

Comment: @terdon, that’s exactly what’s going on all the time: a terminal emulator is connected to another process via a tty and the `$TERM` environment variable tells the other end of the connection about the terminal capabilities. This is the case whether that other process is on the same machine or a remote host. Locally, it is set by the terminal emulator when it forks the shell. When you make an SSH connection, SSH transmits certain variables to the remote host, normally including `TERM`, and should ideally be configured to transmit all variables beginning with “TERM”.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a portable way to get the name or path of the parent process:

iTerm 2:

```
$ ps -p $(ps -p $$ -o ppid=) -o comm=
/Applications/iTerm.app/Contents/MacOS/iTerm
```

gnome-terminal in Ubuntu:

```
$ ps -p $(ps -p $$ -o ppid=) -o comm=
gnome-terminal
```

Terminal.app:

```
$ ps -p $(ps -p $$ -o ppid=) -o comm=
login
```

Note that if Terminal.app is set to open new shells with the default login shell, the parent process of the shell is `login` and not the terminal.

The `comm` column is the full path of the command in OS X and the command name truncated to 15 characters in the procps implementation in Linux.

Comment: Tried in iTerm and got `login` -- Did I customize my profile some time back to run the command `login -fp danielbeck`?